# string to array conversion is empty when in WSL but works fine in linux

Tags: linux, bash, macos, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying out this simple commands in WSL (Ubuntu):

```
$ OS="windows redhat centos ubuntu"
$ ARR_OS=($OS)
$ echo ${ARR_OS[0]}
<BLANK OUTPUT>
$ echo ${ARR_OS[1]}
windows redhat centos ubuntu
```

And it has a different output if the same commands executed in Linux:

```
$ OS="windows redhat centos ubuntu"
$ ARR_OS=($OS)
$ echo ${ARR_OS[0]}
windows
$ echo ${ARR_OS[1]}
redhat
```

I was expecting that WSL works very similar with Ubuntu Linux but I'm having some difficulty trying to get this to work.

Any idea why WSL output is not the same?

**EDIT**:
I have attached a sample run in my WSL terminal and incorporate suggestions in the comments as well

**SEE**: 
[Screenshot of WSL Terminal Output in Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LALTz.png)

Strange, I have tried the exact commands in **OSX** and produces the same result:

```
→ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

→ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

→ OS="windows redhat centos ubuntu"

→ ARR_OS=($OS)

→ declare -p ARR_OS
typeset -a ARR_OS=( 'windows redhat centos ubuntu' )

→ echo ${ARR_OS[0]}
<BLANK>

→ echo ${ARR_OS[1]}
windows redhat centos ubuntu
```

**UPDATE**:
I have found this excellent post that explains the array differences when in zsh and bash:
https://blog.mimacom.com/arrays-on-linux-shell/

Comment: I am not sure about this, but can you tell me the output of `echo $SHELL` on each of those.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Works for me as expected on Linux *and* in WSL. Are you sure you entered the exact same command as shown here? Please try to reproduce your problem by copy-pasting (!) the commands from this question into your WSL shell. PS: Instead of `echo ...` you can use `declare -p ARR_OS` to debug the values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited my question to include a sample run thru my WSL. You can take a look on the actual output.

Comment: @JVS: Your sample does not say match. Printing the variable SHELL does not necessarily tell you which shell you are running, so this information is nearly useless. The OSX example likely uses zsh which explains why you get the behaviour. While not 100% reliable, a good indicator to see whether you are under bash or zsh is outputting BASH_VERSION and ZSH_VERSION. While this can be faked, it is unlikely that someone does.

Comment: @JVS: The output you get on WSL would be expected if you run on Zsh instead of bash. Verify that you are indeed under bash!

Comment: Is there any point of reference why the command will not run as expected when in ZSH mode?

Comment: The easiest way to find which shell you are currently using is to look at the 2nd last line of `ps`' output (except you/someone renamed the shell's executable to something different).

Comment: The "first" entry is empty because [arrays in `zsh` are indexed starting from 1](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts), not from 0 as in `bash`.

Comment: Thanks @Socowi, this all makes sense now. I have to set "zsh -y" and I am able to get individual item in the array starting in 1.